# Mysql repeat column value till with condition

Tags: mysql

I've a table :

[image]

I want the value of the driver to be repeated in the incoming rows in column driver until io_1 become 0, it set it to 0

Comment: ... if `io_1` become 1 again what value must be used for `driver`?

Comment: repeat the same things, io_1 is car ignition sensor (0 off,1 on), driver id is the enter by the driver before he starts the car. as long as the ignition is on or io_1 =1 it repeats the first driver values it recieves, set it to 0 once the ignition is off or io_1 =0

Comment: `driver` have the only value (except zeros) over all the table? If so then make this column generated.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=436886fa7c68d974d558c55c8357c077

Comment: thank you for your support, but data is coming automatically from the IoT device and it sends driver only one time example:

io_data: {time: 2021-08-10 14:02:02 , io_1: 1 , driver: 17EB0C401000065}
io_data: {time: 2021-08-10 14:02:03 , io_1: 1 , driver: 0}
io_data: {time: 2021-08-10 14:02:04 , io_1: 1 , driver: 0}
io_data: {time: 2021-08-10 14:02:05 , io_1: 1 , driver: 0}
io_data: {time: 2021-08-10 14:02:06 , io_1: 1 , driver: 0}
I want a way to repeat  17EB0C401000065 instead of 0, and set it to 0 one this condition:
io_data: {time: 2021-08-10 14:02:07 , io_1: 0 , driver: 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update existing data:

```
UPDATE test
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MAX(driver) driver
             FROM test ) data
SET test.driver = data.driver
WHERE test.io_1;
```

Autofill during further insertions:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
ON test
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.driver = CASE WHEN io_1 = 0
                      THEN 0
                      ELSE ( SELECT MAX(driver)
                             FROM test );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d19f25bf3b40732b65d3eeb3f8fbe6bc

Comment: Hi thank you so much it works as expected, but when I change the driver name it returns the same old value, 
INSERT INTO test (io_1,driver) VALUES (1,'ammar');
how can I apply for all drivers

Comment: @ammardimiaty Now imagine... Some external process inserts a row with the values (1,0). There are 2 different non-zero `driver` values in the table. Now explain me, how to distinguish what value from this two possible ones must be inserted instead of zero?

Comment: Hi @Akina,  I'm facing this issue in the real world where 2 drivers start one bus scenario will be:
{time: 2021-08-10 14:02:05 , io_1: 1 , driver: driver1} -- driver1 started the bus on the
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{time: 2021-08-10 14:10:10 , io_1: 1 , driver: driver2} -- driver 2 started bus
in this case the column driver should exchange driver1 with driver 2, -- update with the latest driver

in case if io_1 = 0 , driver =0 and anyway from IoT I configure device to send driver 0 when io_1 =0

Comment: @ammardimiaty *update with the latest driver* The table is unordered heap. So the terms "first-last-next-etc." not exists until the column which uniquely sets the rows order exists (created_at, for example). Your data have no such column - so the task is unsolvable in current schema state. Recommendation - add service table which will store `driver` value for the latest non-zero one, and update it each time when non-zero value is inserted.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Akina, I complete the table structure   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=416b0a800a439bce0a2d723307cb325f  but was not successful can you please help

Comment: @ammardimiaty I recommend you to create new question. Post the task description, link to the fiddle, the query which inserts more data (provided by the device) and the final daata state which must be obtained (after needed inserted data corrections).